# Moment.js Why Dates with provided year + week gives the previous week?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hello I am using moment to create a week Calendar:

Current Week #26 -> From Sunday June 27th to Saturday July 3th

```
const year = 2021;
const week = 26;

moment().year(year).week(week). // prints Sun Jun 20 2021 10:36:14 GMT-0500
```

Why I obtain the previous week ?

Short Answer I can plus one, but I do not understand why :(

BAD thing:

```
    const startDay = moment(
      moment().year(year).week(week + 1)
    )
      .startOf('week');

    const endDay = moment(
      moment().year(year).week(week + 1)
    )
      .endOf('week');
```

Extra info:

```
moment().year(2021).week(1) // Sun Dec 27 2020 10:51:41 GMT-0600
```

instead of January 3th to January 9th

Answer (score 1):

Try using `moment.utc` which should convert all the dates according to the Universal time